# python iter over dict-like object

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

```
 class Test(object):

     def __init__(self, store):
         assert isinstance(store, dict)
         self.store = store

     def __getitem__(self, key):
         return self.store[key]
```

I try to iter over this class. It is said in [this doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)  that implementing __getitem__ should be enough to iter over my Test class. Indeed, when I try to iter over it, it does not tell me that I can't, but I've got a *KeyError*:

```
In [10]: a = Test({1:1,2:2})

In [11]: for i in a: print i
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8c9c9a8afa41> in <module>()
----> 1 for i in a: print i

<ipython-input-9-17212ae08f42> in __getitem__(self, key)
      4         self.store = store
      5     def __getitem__(self, key):
----> 6         return self.store[key]
      7

KeyError: 0
```

- **Do you know where this 0 come from ?** (what's going on under the hood)

I know I can solve it by adding an __iter__ function:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return dict.__iter__(self.store)
```

- **Is it the best way to solve this problem ?** (I might also inherit from dict class).

Comment: The best way to solve what problem, what that class should be doing? Class has only `dict` value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed a crucial wording in the documentation you found:

> For ***sequence types***, the accepted keys should be integers and slice objects. *[...]* [I]f of a value outside the set of indexes ***for the sequence*** (after any special interpretation of negative values), `IndexError` should be raised.
>
> **Note**: `for` loops expect that an `IndexError` will be raised for illegal indexes to allow proper detection of the end ***of the sequence***.

Bold italic emphasis is mine. If you accept *keys*, not integers, you don't have a sequence.

The Python glossary explains more; see the [definition of *sequence*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence):

> An iterable which supports efficient element access using ***integer indices via the `__getitem__()` special method*** and defines a `__len__()` method that returns the length of the sequence. *[...]* Note that `dict` also supports `__getitem__()` and `__len__()`, but is considered a mapping rather than a sequence because the lookups use arbitrary immutable keys rather than integers.

So sequences accept integer indices, and that's exactly what `for` provides when iterating <sup>*</sup>. When given an object to iterate over, if there are no other means but `__getitem__` available, then a special iterator is constructed that starts at `0` and keeps increasing the counter until `IndexError` is raised. In pure Python that'd be:

```
def getitem_iterator(obj):
    getitem = type(obj).__getitem__  # special method, so on the type
    index = 0
    try:
        while True:
            yield getitem(obj, index)
            index += 1
    except IndexError:
        # iteration complete
        return
```

The actual implementation is in C, see the [`PySeqIter_Type` definition and functions](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/iterobject.c).

Implement the [`__iter__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) instead; it is used when present. Since you wrap a dictionary, you could simply return the iterator for that dictionary (use the [`iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) rather than directly call special methods):

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.store)
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Technically speaking, `for` doesn't provide this. `for` just uses `iter(obj)` and it is *that call* that produces the special iterator when no `__iter__` method is available instead.